# 502 Bad Gateway in Nginx when trying to connecting GCP sql instance for database perform

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nginx, google-cloud-platform, prisma

I have a node application hosted on a GCP VM instance with Nginx here is my Nginx configuration

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

     root /var/www/html;

     # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     server_name _;

     location / {
             # First attempt to serve request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

server running on pm2 and here the logs

```
/root/.pm2/logs/edvive-out.log last 15 lines:
0|edvive   | 14/Dec/2022:09:50:22 +0000 "GET /api/v1/users/gcp-data"
0|edvive   | 14/Dec/2022:09:50:23 +0000 "GET /api/v1/users/gcp-data"
0|edvive   | user api hitted
0|edvive   | The server is running at port: 5000
0|edvive   | user api hitted
0|edvive   | The server is running at port: 5000
0|edvive   | 14/Dec/2022:09:51:01 +0000 "GET /api/v1/users/gcp-data"
0|edvive   | 14/Dec/2022:09:51:30 +0000 "GET /api/v1/users/gcp-data"
0|edvive   | user api hitted
0|edvive   | The server is running at port: 5000
0|edvive   | user api hitted
0|edvive   | The server is running at port: 5000
0|edvive   | user api hitted
0|edvive   | The server is running at port: 5000
0|edvive   | 14/Dec/2022:10:04:13 +0000 "GET /"
```

I hit the API http://35.**.**.***/api/v1/users/ under this route server needs to perform a database that is hosted on the GCP Postgres SQL instance and I added the VM instance IP address into the SQL connection

```
Authorized networks
You can specify CIDR ranges to allow IP addresses in those ranges to access your instance. Learn more

production (35.***.**.***)
local (118.***.***.***)
```

this SQL instance is connected to the node js app with a database URL for Prisma connection in the env file

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:password@34.***.***.***:5432/postgres"
```

I can access this database from my local machine. If I try to get data I can get it from the postman but with the GCP URL http://35.***.**.***/api/v1/users/ it shows a 502 error bad gateway. But anything that did not need to perform database that gave me a response and there are no Nginx errors. here is Nginx error logs

```
2022/12/14 10:03:20 [error] 5650#5650: *201 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 118.***.***.***, server: _, reque>
2022/12/14 10:03:20 [error] 5650#5650: *201 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.***.***.**, server: _, request: "GET /a>
<a HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/api/v1/users/gcp-data", host: "35.***.**.***"
```

I think it is maybe an error for the database URL that Nginx can not find

How can I solve it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi as you have mentioned this has nothing to do with your nginx configuration. you are getting this error because your database connection is getting failed. I have tried deploying using a similar kind of connection string but it’s not working. So, I have referred to the google docs on the postgres connection examples and they have mentioned how to use env variables and knex module for connecting to cloudsql prostgres. Refer these two links for more information on [knex](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/samples/cloud-sql-postgres-knex-connect-unix) module and [postgres connectors](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview#node.js)